# Getting Error when sending images to /upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I have a node application which sends formData to /upload. I designed the app to send one request per file. When I ran it sending 40 requests, it worked. I ran it again right after with 50 requests to test and now I'm sending the following error on the host server while watching the process with pm2 logs:

```
0|football-strapi  |   Error: Parse Error
0|football-strapi  |       at socketOnEnd (_http_server.js:540:22)
0|football-strapi  |       at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
0|football-strapi  |       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
0|football-strapi  |       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue? This is Strapi v3.

Thank You